# Find value of div inside aura iteration on icon click!

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, aura-iteration

I am trying to find the value of a div which is inside aura iteration on icon click which is also inside the same aura iteration. Here in this code below I am trying to find the value of the aura:id=streeAddress on the click of the icon below.

```
<aura:iteration items="{! v.filteredMduInfo }" var="mdu">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div aura:id="streetAddress">{!
                mdu.address.Name+', '+mdu.address.sumchans__city__c+'
                '+mdu.address.sumchans__provinceCode__c+' '+mdu.address.sumchans__postalCode__c }</div>
        </div>
        <div>                    
            <lightning:icon iconName="utility:desktop" alternativeText="Television"
                            size="small" onclick="{! c.tvIconClick }"/>
        </div>
    </div>              
</aura:iteration>
```

Controller JS:

```
tvIconClick : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log(component.find("streetAddress").get());        
},
```

Comment: Your code has an extra `</div>` and is missing several closing elements near the end; this code would not compile as is. If it were nested correctly. As such, I'm not sure how we can help you as is. Would you please [edit] your code so that it is structurally correct? That will affect the answer you'd receive, as there are several possible solutions available.

Comment: @sfdcfox I got the original post edited based on your request. Plz advise!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly do this with the information you get in the event handler as is. Instead, you can use the index or record Id to find the value.

```
<aura:iteration items="{! v.filteredMduInfo }" var="mdu" indexVar="mduIndex">
    <div data-record-id="{!v.mdu.Id}" data-index="{!mduIndex}">
        <div>
            <div aura:id="streetAddress">{!
                mdu.address.Name+', '+mdu.address.sumchans__city__c+'
                '+mdu.address.sumchans__provinceCode__c+' '+mdu.address.sumchans__postalCode__c }</div>
        </div>
        <div>                    
            <lightning:icon iconName="utility:desktop" alternativeText="Television"
                            size="small" onclick="{! c.tvIconClick }"/>
        </div>
    </div>              
</aura:iteration>
```

---

```
tvIconClick : function(component, event, helper) {
  var filteredMdu = component.get("v.filteredMduInfo"),
      wrapper = event.target.closest("[data-record-id]"); // or [data-index]
  // option 1
  console.log(filteredMdu.find(mdu => mdu.Id === wrapper.dataset.recordId));
  // option 2
  console.log(filteredMdu[parseInt(wrapper.dataset.index)]);
},
```

Either way, these would be appropriate methods for finding the correct record to work with.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. Got the code copied exactly the way you posted here. It didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I was able to figure it out this way, I added a title attribute with the id value to lightning:icon. Got the value on the controller using the event.getSource().